# SQL Combinations of multiple rows over same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to merge cells together by every combination ordered alphabetically. i.e. a line for every possible pair, set of 3, set of 4, etc.

Info that might help; Every ID will have between 2 and 6 parts to it, and will say how many parts the ID has.

i.e. My data currently looks like this;

```
    ID | Number_of_parts | Part_no. | Description | Price

    1          3              1         Apple        0.50
    1          3              2         Cucumber     0.25
    1          3              3         Banana       0.30
    2          2              1         Donut        1.00
    2          2              2         Banana       0.40
```

and I would like to get the following result;

```
    ID  | Desc1 | Price1 | Desc2 | Price2 | Desc3 | Price3 | Desc4 | Price4

    1     Apple    0.50    Banana    0.30   Cucumber   0.25    NULL    NULL
    1     Apple    0.50    Banana    0.30    NULL      NULL    NULL    NULL
    1     Apple    0.50    Cucumber  0.25    NULL      NULL    NULL    NULL
    1     Banana   0.30    Cucumber  0.25    NULL      NULL    NULL    NULL
    2     Banana   0.40    Donut     1.00    NULL      NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have so far?  We need a starting point to work with to see how you're currently attempting this...

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: can you get a pair of 5 or 10 or so on? In that case how do you want to handle the output with 4 levels?

Comment: Question states each ID can have 2-6 parts, so 6 pairs of Desc/Price columns will be needed each time.   When an ID has fewer than 6, then the unneeded columns will be populated with NULLs.   At least, that's how I read it.   The more I think about it, the more I think each of the Price/Desc columns needs to be either a CASE statement or a sub-query.   Probably a sub-query.  Or maybe a recursive CTE would be useful here?   My head hurts.

Comment: Currently, I am able to combine the various lines with same ID into a single line containing all items. @Tab Alleman, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are restricted to four possibilities, then you can use `left join`.  The following almost works:

```
select d1.id,
       d1.desc as desc1, d1.price as price1,
       d2.desc as desc2, d2.price as price2,
       d3.desc as desc3, d3.price as price3,
       d4.desc as desc4, d4.price as price4
from data d1 left join
     data d2
     on d1.id = d2.id and d1.partno < d2.partno left join
     data d3
     on d1.id = d3.id and d2.partno < d3.partno left join
     data d4
     on d1.id = d4.id and d3.partno < d4.partno;
```

The problem is that it will not give apple/banana.  So, you seem to want pairs at a minimum.  Then I think the easiest way to get pairs is to use `UNION`:

```
select d1.id,
       d1.desc as desc1, d1.price as price1,
       d2.desc as desc2, d2.price as price2,
       d3.desc as desc3, d3.price as price3,
       d4.desc as desc4, d4.price as price4
from data d1 join
     data d2
     on d1.id = d2.id and d1.partno < d2.partno left join
     data d3
     on d1.id = d3.id and d2.partno < d3.partno left join
     data d4
     on d1.id = d4.id and d3.partno < d4.partno;
union
select d1.id,
       d1.desc as desc1, d1.price as price1,
       d2.desc as desc2, d2.price as price2,
       NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
       d3.desc as desc3, d3.price as price3,
       d4.desc as desc4, d4.price as price4
from data d1 join
     data d2
     on d1.id = d2.id and d1.partno < d2.partno;
```

Comment: How can that UNION be valid when you've added 4 extra NULL columns to the bottom half?

Comment: No there are far more than 4 possibilities (there are unaccountably many) unfortunately. Even if I could get pairs, 3s and 4s that would be hugely helpful

Comment: @Bob . . . A SQL query has a fixed number of columns.  You would need a different representation if you have an unlimited number of combos in a group.